# TypeError: Attempting to change the setter of an unconfigurable property. phantomjs + vue 3

Tags: phantomjs, vuejs3

My project is in vuejs.
I have written simple script to take screenshot of login page using phantomjs.
But, No luck :-(

I have been searching solution for the above error from last 4 days.

Code :

```
'use strict'

var page = require("webpage").create();

page.open("http://localhost:8080/login", function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    page.render("login.png");
    phantom.exit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

Result :

As result, I am getting a blank image with a loading symbol.

I am using ubuntu 20.04
phantomjs version is 2.1.1

Please help me to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: It's unknown what went wrong in your case. Phantom is really stale browser and may not work without polyfills, or not work at all depending on your app, which is unknown. Just don't use it

Comment: Hi, @EstusFlask Thanks for your reply.
You are right the package is deprecated.
But, It is in my project requirements that I have to write headless UI tests using phantomjs.

Comment: It's a ridiculous requirement that you possibly won't be able to fulfill and could question at the time of its appearance. Currently it's Puppeteer that should be used. The only thing you can do is to make the website workable in stale browsers like IE11 and Chrome <=27 (primarily the latter, because Phantom is closely related), by adding polyfills and Babel transforms. If it uses things that cannot work in old browsers any way, you're out of luck. Currently the question contains nothing that could help to suggest a solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay, thanks for the detailed information.
Would you please suggest to me a good testing library which works awesome with vue3?

Comment: jest+Vue Testing Library for unit/integration. jest-puppeteer or cypress for integration/e2e, it doesn't matter if it's Vue or anything else for e2e